# Getting the date info in a MySQL friendly way

Tags: php, mysql, date

Got two questions. 
I pass a date like 05/16/1978 and I want it to be converted to a format that's friendly to the datetime field of a MySQL table.

And secondly, how do you get the current time in php? Something like 17:22:59

Comment: You have two questions here which are closely connected - usually you'll want to stay with one question per post.

Comment: -1 for not refering to the documents. These are basic functions well explained in the docs

Comment: @VIP - just to let you know - the original poster of a question receives notifications for new answers on his post...  There is no need to comment about your answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
function convert_time_sql($date){
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date("Y-m-d ",$date).date("G:i:s");
    return $date;
}
```

this will return the sql format time

**NOTE:**  Date must be of proper format see:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php

**EDIT:**

Use this function if time is included:

```
function convert_time_sql($date,$time_included=false){
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date("Y-m-d ".($time_included?"G:i:s":""),$date).($time_included?"":date("G:i:s"));
    return $date;
}
```

If you include time, put a true after the given date.

like  `convert_time_sql('05/16/1978 05:45:59 AM',true);`

Comment: Vipin Jain, thank you for addressing the question. That does the job. There is one problem though. if the date passed contains time information ( such as 05/16/1978 05:45:59 or 05/16/1978 05:45:59 AM), how do we bring the time part into mysql format? Yours is always returning the current time. Can you adjust your function so that convert_time_sql is more versatile?

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to look into

- [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp
- [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) - Return current Unix timestamp
- [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - Format a local time/date

Using the `date()` function, you can pass an EPOCH timestamp and get back a string representing the timestamp in any format you desire -

```
$now = time();
$today = date("M d Y",$now);  // May 01 2012
```

Check out the [date function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for details about what formats are possible...

You can always store dates in EPOCH format (seconds since 1/1/70).  I find it very easy to use and manipulate EPOCH timestamps. I use `INT(10)` fields in my database to store these values.

---

Here is a fantastic tool for you to use if you decide to implement your timestamps by EPOCH -

http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: The downvote is because it's silly to save a time as an integer when there are are types made specifically for the purpose of storing dates and timestamps. It's just wrong. Besides, you won't be able to use any of the `DATE*` functions such as `DATEDIFF`, `ADDDATE`, etc. So, get off your high horse - perhaps somebody just doesn't agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this link please

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

e.g.

```
$d = "05/16/1978";
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/",$d);
$datetime = sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $year, $month, $day);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DATETIME` format is `YYYY-MM-DD`, in order to convert your result to that, you can do

```
$date = "05/16/1978";
list($month, $day, $year) = explode("/",$date);
$datetime = sprintf("%d-%d-%d", $year, $month, $day);
```

`$datetime` would now contain "1978-16-15", which MySQL will understand.

`date('G:i:s')` will return the current time in the format H:m:s.

Answer (score 1):

Read this [Dates in PHP and MySQL](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql) blog post, I think it might help you.

It summarizes three possibilites of managing dates that are stored in MySQL using PHP. A common way that is mentioned there is:

> One common solution is to store the dates in DATETIME fields and use PHPs date() and strtotime() functions to convert between PHP timestamps and MySQL DATETIMEs.

For example:

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Lix, thanks a lot, I tried to put more details in my answer. I appreciate your comment and will definitely notice that in my future answers.

Comment: Great to hear! Happy coding! :)